# Is there a syntactical way to shorten a long if conditional?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Is there a syntactical way to shorten a long if conditional like in the example below

```
if (invoice.get('status') !== 'claimed' && invoice.get('status') !== 'paid' && invoice.get('status') !== 'cancelled' )
```

to

```
if (invoice.get('status') !== 'claimed' && 'paid' && 'cancelled' )
```

or something like

```
if (invoice.get('status') !== 'claimed', 'paid', 'cancelled' )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take an array with the not wanted values and check with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

```
if (!['claimed', 'paid', 'cancelled'].includes(invoice.get('status')) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!['claimed', 'paid', 'cancelled'].includes(invoice.get('status'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten it by using an Array of status:

```
if (!['claimed', 'paid', 'cancelled'].includes(invoice.get('status')))
```